# keeping track of nested ng-repeat index's

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a nested ng-repeat like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in flow" ng-init="$flowIndex = $index">

    Index: {{ $index }}
    <div ng-click="flow.splice($index, 1)">Delete me</div>

    <div ng-repeat="inside_data in flow[$flowIndex]">
        Inside index: {{ $index }}
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to be able to delete index in my `$flowIndex`. However if I have something like this:

```
0 
1
2
3
```

And I delete index `2`. If I go and delete index `3`, it isn't found because ng-init variable still things its at index 3 but really its not at index 2.

Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: When you delete index 2 using the `ng-click`, it should trigger a digest cycle which will re-execute the `ng-repeat` and cause the item that was previously index 3 to have index 2. Are you doing something outside of AngularJS so that the digest doesn't occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of `$flowIndex`, it's not necessary, you can use `$parent.$index` instead, when you are using `ngRepeat` it creates a child scope and `$index` is part of that scope. Also consider moving your deleting logic into the controller.

Controller:

```
$scope.delete = function ($index) {
    $scope.flow.splice($index, 1);
};
```

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in flow">

    Index: {{ $index }}
    <div ng-click="delete($index)">Delete me</div>

    <div ng-repeat="inside_data in flow[$index]">
        Inside index: {{ $parent.$index }} -> {{ $index }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, however I have found out that `ng-repeat` should still be `$index` and not `$parent.$index`

Comment: @bryan you're right, it belongs to the parent scope at that point. Therefore, it's not necessary to user `$parent` because it's already on `$parent`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get the parent index like so:

```
$parent.$index
```

As mentioned in this answer: [passing 2 $index values within nested ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256600/passing-2-index-values-within-nested-ng-repeat)

That way you don't have to worry about your variable being out of sync with your current state.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your similar code with some dummy data strings and the delete appears to work. I made some updates to your code to better analyze it.

```js
// Code goes here

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.flow = [
    ["test01","test02","test03"],
    ["test11","test12","test13"],
    ["test21","test22","test23"],
    ["test31","test32","test33"],
    ["test41","test42","test43"]
  ]
  ;
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="//opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <section ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-repeat="data in flow">
  
      Index: {{ $index }}
      <div ng-click="flow.splice($index, 1)">Delete me [{{ $index }}]</div>
  
      <div ng-repeat="inside_data in flow[$index]">
          Inside index: {{ $index }} : {{ inside_data }}
      </div>
      <hr>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```